# How to create bulk page and content?

Tags: database, bulk, bulk-import

I am creating a website about cars. I want to have a page for each car, with subpages (i.e. Gallery, Specs, etc...) for each car page. I have the content on my hard drive for each car. Doing this manually will take forever, so i was thinking of writing a code (maybe in python) that will fill the contents for each car into an html file; however, i read that Wordpress doesn't store files but instead keeps the content in a database. So my question is, what's the best way to create bulk pages and upload them to Wordpress? Is there a plugin which i'm missing that can do this?

Thanks.

Comment: If you have command-line access to your WP server, you could use [WP-CLI's `wp post generate` command](http://loripsum.net/api/5).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest manually creating your first page (a custom post type might make more sense here?) in WordPress and then use the fantastic [WP CSV](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-csv/) plugin to export the page.

Using the first page fields as a guide, simply copy your car data into the appropriate cell in a chart and import the completed CSV data when finished.

Comment: Thanks, what about images? can I also include these somehow?

Comment: Absolutely.  Depending on how you are using the image (WP featured/thumbnail, custom field, meta) for your post or CPT, the WP CSV export will show you the field name (as a column for mass filling) and the syntax/format to use.  When you create that first post, add your image as you'd like them all to be done, export and voila.